# Kernel panic while loading shared libraries libc.so.6

Tags: command-line, kernel

I was developing my so library it wasn't working properly

I ran the command `ln -nsf /myLibrary /libc.so.6` in order to link my lib to `libc` but it linked `libc` to my lib as I understood, then I rebooted pc, know I’m getting kernel panic:

[image]

Is there any way to fix it? I even can't enter command-line mode

Comment: what wasnt working about the previous version?
is this x86_64?  For 64-bit Ubuntu:
`sudo ln -s /lib64/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib64/libc.so.6`
to get back to the original. can you boot into single user mode? else, you might need a boot disk

Comment: thanks mate for help, I explained how I was able to fix it, you helped me understand that I can do nothing without boot disk

Answer (score 1):

I made a flash disk with ubuntu, ran it in try mode, found my file `/medium/../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`

I ran commands:

`unlink /medium/../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`

then I copied live cd `libc.so.6` version of file to my hard disk.

and checked shared libraries by calling

`sudo ldd /medium/../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`

then rebooted PC

I don't know what exactly helped me, but now I'm able to boot my Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue solved it by following steps:

1.Make a bootable USB [In my case I used Ubuntu 20.04]

2.Choose the Try Ubuntu option when the system boots.

3.Download the libc.so.6 from the below link according to your architecture.

https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libc.so.6

4.Or a better practice as I used  copied the libc.so.6 from a working ubuntu PC to
drive and downloaded it on the affected PC.

5. Mount your root partition using the following cmd
   sudo mount /dev/<root_partition>  /mnt
   cd /mnt/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
6. Do not delete the older libc.so.6 file as the terminal will become useless if its
   deleted ,instead copy the downloaded libc.so.6 file to this location i.e
   /mnt/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
7. Reboot your PC and you will be good to go.